# Does every dma_map_single call require a corresponding dma_unmap_single?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm porting a large code base to a Linux kernel device driver. The ASIC uses a huge number of DMA channels.

I kmalloc memory with `GFP_KERNEL|GFP_DMA`. Before starting the DMA, I use dma_map_single to get the hardware (physical) memory address to feed to the hardware. (Also does a flush/invalidate the memory from dcache?) I sometimes need CPU access to the data once DMA is complete, but not often. Before I access the data via code, I do a dma_unmap_single to avoid cache coherency issues.

In the cases where I do not ever need CPU access, do I still need to call `dma_unmap_single`? Should I `dma_unmap_single` every pointer I `dma_map_single`? Does `dma_map_single` consume a resource (e.g., table entry) that `dma_unmap_single` will release?

The DMA-API.txt isn't clear on good DMA memory hygiene.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `dma_map_single` you map the memory for DMA transfer. You get the physical pointer to the memory, so the device can DMA to that address.

With `dma_unmap_single` you unmap the memory mapped above. You should do this when your transfers are over.

You can *map* a memory region, and use it for multiple DMA transfers and then you *unmap* when the job is done. Each time you want to access the DMA memory you must synchronize it. If the device is going to access the memory, you should do `dma_sync_single_for_device`; it the host is going to access the memory, you should do `dma_sync_single_for_cpu`

Comment: Is it that "dma_map_single" simply converts virtual to physical address ?

Comment: *simply* is a big word, quick and dirty anser is 'yes'. Follow the [implementation](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/dma-mapping.h#L123) for details. Check also the [DMA API documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/DMA-API.txt) because is the best reference than any word on stackoverflow :)

Comment: dma_map_single is converting virtual address to bus address, to be precise. Bus address can be different from physical address. I think https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/DMA-API-HOWTO.txt is more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer:**

Yes. You should `dma_unmap_single` every buffer you have been mapped with `dma_map_single`.

**Long Answer:**

Also yes.
You should call `dma_unmap_single` at the end of every DMA transaction.

But since `dma_map_single / dma_unmap_single` is an expensive operation, sometimes we may prefer (when the packet is not too big) to reuse the DMA-mapped buffer, so instead of calling `dma_unmap_single` at the end of the DMA transaction, we are calling `dma_sync_single_for_cpu`, then copying the data from the DMA-mapped buffer into some other buffer, and then calling `dma_sync_single_for_device`, so now we can reuse the already DMA-mapped buffer without unmapping and remapping it again before our next DMA transaction.

I guess the threshold of how big the packet varies between architectures and should be measured.

```
measure_time(dma_sync_single_for_cpu + memcpy(packet_size) + dma_sync_single_for_device) 
>?<
measure_time(dma_unmap_single + dma_map_single)
```

**Short Example:**

```
    if (frame_len < FRAME_LEN_THRESHOLD) {            
        skb = netdev_alloc_skb_ip_align(priv->dev, frame_len);
        if (unlikely(!skb)) {
            printk("packet dropped\n");
            continue;
        }
        
        dma_sync_single_for_cpu(priv->device, rx_skbuff_dma[entry],                                   
                                frame_len, DMA_FROM_DEVICE);

        // same as memcpy
        skb_copy_to_linear_data(skb, rx_skbuff[entry]->data, frame_len);

        dma_sync_single_for_device(priv->device, rx_skbuff_dma[entry],
                                   frame_len, DMA_FROM_DEVICE);

        /* now we can reuse rx_skbuff_dma[entry]. 
           no need to call dma_unmap_single */                           
    } else {
        skb = rx_skbuff[entry];
        if (unlikely(!skb)) {
            printk("packet dropped\n");
            continue;
        }

        rx_skbuff[entry] = NULL;

        dma_unmap_single(priv->device, rx_skbuff_dma[entry],
                         priv->dma_buffer_size, DMA_FROM_DEVICE);

        /* if we want to use rx_skbuff_dma[entry] for another DMA transaction, 
           we will need to realocate a buffer and call dma_map_single */                 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the dma_map api may allocate bounce buffers,  in this case, you will need to call the dma_unmap function.